# Ada...Procedures not visible from main

Tags: generics, ada

I am just starting in Ada and I am having trouble figuring it out.

I have main.adb, createlist.adb & createlist.ads (code to follow)

I am getting the error

> "print_list" is not visible (more references follow)

> non-visible declaration at createlist.ads:(whatever line number)

for every procedure and function.

I have tried it without all within main and it works there so I already know the procedures do what they are supposed to when they are visible. I'm just not sure what I'm doing wrong to make them non-visible. I have been all over the class notes, google, github, here and various other forums to figure it out but have yet to find the solution.

main.adb

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Float_Text_IO;
use Ada.Float_Text_IO;
with CreateList;



procedure Main is

   max: integer;
   pointer: integer;
   len: integer;

   package IntIO is new Ada.Text_IO.Integer_IO(Integer); use IntIO;

begin

   Put("What size is the array? ");
   get(max);

      declare

      list: array (1 .. max) of Integer;

   begin
      list := (others => 0);
      pointer := 0;
      len := 0;

      print_list;
      add_to_list(12);
      add_to_list(3);
      add_to_list(7);
      print_list;
      len := length_of_list;
      for pointer in 1 .. len loop
         print_list;
      end loop;
      Put_Line("");
      delete_from_list(2);
      print_list;
   end;

end Main;
```

createlist.adb

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Float_Text_IO;
use Ada.Float_Text_IO;

package body CreateList is -- in file CreateList.adb
   len: Integer;
   list: array(1..max) of itemType;

   procedure add_to_list (ListItem: in itemType) is begin
      if pnt >= max then
            Put_Line("**Detected Overflow**");
         else
            pnt := pnt + 1;
            list(pnt) := ListItem;
         end if;
      null;
   end add_to_list;

   procedure delete_from_list (indx: in Integer) is begin
      if indx = 0 then
            Put_Line("**Detected Underflow**");
      else
         for j in indx .. (pnt - 1) loop
            if j < len then
               list(j) := list(j + 1);
            end if;
         end loop;

         pnt := pnt - 1;
      end if;
      null;
   end delete_from_list;

   function length_of_list return Integer is begin
      return len;
   end length_of_list;

   procedure print_list (indx: in Integer) is begin
      Put(list(indx));
      Put(" ");
      null;
   end print_list;

   procedure print_list is begin
      for i in 1 .. max loop
         Put(list(i));
         Put(" ");
      end loop;
      Put_Line("");
      null;
   end print_list;

end CreateList;
```

createlist.ads

```
generic
   max: integer;
   type itemType is private;

package CreateList is
      
   procedure add_to_list (listItem: in itemType);
   --   
   procedure delete_from_list (indx: in itemType);
   --   
   function length_of_list return itemType;
   --
   procedure print_list (indx: in itemType);
   procedure print_list;

end CreateList;
```

I am also having trouble passing the pointer.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Understanding visibility is key to understanding Ada. As the error msg says, there is nothing named Print_List visible in procedure Main. If Createlist were a package, you could call the procedure Print_List that it declares as `Createlist.Print_List;` However, Createlist is not a pkg, it is a generic pkg, and so can only be used to create pkgs through the process of generic instantiation: `package Instantiation_Name is new Createlist (Max => 42, Itemtype => Whatever);` If you had done that, you could then call `Instantiation_Name.Print_List;`

Comment: Or having instantiated the generic package, you can `Use Instantiation_Name;` and the procedures will be visible. If you instantiate it twice for different types MOST of them will appear, correctly resolved by their parameter type, but parameterless `printlist` will not. Which is good : it makes you use `Instantiation_Name.printlist` so you print the correct list.

Comment: Instantiation got it. Thank you very much

Comment: @JesseSchultz: Please [edit] your question to show your revised approach, or you can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188).